# Searching contacts on Android

Tags: stock-android

On Android v7

1. click Phone
2. click the Contacts icon (two human silhouettes)
3. click [Create new contact]
4. create new contact

Contact is added and shows up in the list. It also shows in the Google Contacts Web UI on a desktop as well as in Gmail.
However, searching for this contact from the Phone app fails to find it.
The Contacts app is able to find it just fine, just not the Phone app. I installed two other third-party contact searching apps and they find it just fine. It's only the Phone app that has trouble.

Comment: Stupid assumption maybe – but does that new contact have a phone number entered? If not, the phone app might ignore it as it has no use for it anyway (you cannot call someone who has no number).

Comment: Wow, Izzy, that was not a stupid assumption at all, man. That was exactly the issue. Thanks, man!